# How to read json file (array form) using simple JSON library?

Tags: java, arrays, json

Actually, The example below is an answer somewhere in StackOverFlow.
I tried to use the below code, but,

```
JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\exer4-courses.json"));
```

Above line doesn't work because of the below Exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

Is there any way to read my JSON file?

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "cars": [
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job": "Teacher"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mark",
        "city": "Oslo",
        "cars": [
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job": "Doctor"
    }
]
```

Java code:

```
JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\exer4-courses.json"));

for (Object o : a) {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

    String name = (String) person.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);

    String city = (String) person.get("city");
    System.out.println(city);

    String job = (String) person.get("job");
    System.out.println(job);

    JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars");

    for (Object c : cars) {
      System.out.println(c + "");
    }
  }
```

Comment: It says in file there is no array, but a simple json object.

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: (It's saying that the data in the file is *not* an array.  Ie, what you have shown us above is not what's in the file.)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is quite clear. 
You need to cast to `JSONObject` and not `JSONArray`

```
JSONObject a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\exer4-courses.json"));
```

You could possibly have this structure for your JSON:

```
{
   "records": [
      {
         "name": "John",
         "city": "Berlin",
         "cars": [
            "audi",
            "bmw"
         ],
         "job": "Teacher"
      },
      {
         "name": "Mark",
         "city": "Oslo",
         "cars": [
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
         ],
         "job": "Doctor"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now to iterate you can do:

```
JSONArray records = (JSONArray)a.get("records");

for (Object o : records) {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

    String name = (String) person.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);

    String city = (String) person.get("city");
    System.out.println(city);

    String job = (String) person.get("job");
    System.out.println(job);

    JSONArray cars = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cars");

    for (Object c : cars) {
      System.out.println(c + "");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which implies that the quoted JSON is not what's actually in the file.