# Read Json data from text file C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a text file with below format data

```
[
    {
        "SponsorID": 1,
        "FirstBAID": 7395836
    },
    {
        "SponsorID": 2,
        "FirstBAID": 3509279,
        "SecondBAID": 2947210
    },
    {
        "SponsorID": 3,
        "FirstBAID": 1776294,
        "SecondBAID": 6503843
    },
    {
        "SponsorID": 4,
        "FirstBAID": 8014528,
        "SecondBAID": 6203155
    },
    {
        "SponsorID": 5,
        "FirstBAID": 5968769,
        "SecondBAID": 7410195,
        "ThirdBAID":8950170,
    }
]
```

I want to read this data as a List & then i need to query by SponsorID. 
I have created a class like this

```
public class SponsorInfo
{
    public decimal SponsorID { get; set; }
    public decimal FirstBAID { get; set; }
    public decimal SecondBAID { get; set; }
    public decimal ThirdBAID { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can i read text file data & bind *SponsorInfo* class ?

Comment: You need to use a library link JSON.net - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm

Comment: Here a sample from MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you can have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24887573/1466583

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install Newtonsoft.Json nuget package from NuGet package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then:

```
var jsonText = File.ReadAllText("filepath");
var sponsors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<SponsorInfo>>(jsonText);
```

To query on `SponsorID` you can use LINQ:

```
var sponsor5 = sponsors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SponsorID == 5);
```

If you often need a lookup by `SponsorID`, you could convert the result to a dictionary where the key is the `SponsorID`. This will improve performance as it doesn't need to enumerate through the entire list for each lookup. I also suggest you change the type of `SponsorID` to an `int` instead of a `decimal`.

```
var sponsorsById = sponsors.ToDictionary(x => x.SponsorID);
```

Then you can easily access it like:

```
if (sponsorsById.ContainsKey(5))
    var sponsor5 = sponsorsById[5];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Newtonsoft.Json and then you need use it:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
    {
         public void LoadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                List<SponsorInfo> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SponsorInfo>>(json);
            }
        }


        public class SponsorInfo
        {
            public decimal SponsorID { get; set; }
            public decimal FirstBAID { get; set; }
            public decimal SecondBAID { get; set; }
            public decimal ThirdBAID { get; set; }
        }




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.temp, item.vcc);
            } 

        }

    }
```

Comment: The unused `LoadJson` method is kinda confusing.

Comment: humm...correct make sense.;I can remove this and add in Main but then,I think,i should let it for the person using.Thanks for suggestion between and i suppor your answer as much better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the class by creating a list object

```
public class SponsorInfo
{
    public decimal SponsorID { get; set; }
    public decimal FirstBAID { get; set; }
    public decimal SecondBAID { get; set; }
    public decimal ThirdBAID { get; set; }
}
public class SponsorInfoList
{
    public Dictionary<string, SponsorInfo> SIList { set; get; }
}
```

Deserialize the file as,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SIList >(File.ReadAllText(FileName));
```

Then you can read it,

```
foreach(var listItem in res.SIList )
{
    Console.WriteLine("SponsorID ={0}, FirstBAID ={1},  SecondBAID ={2}, ThirdBAID ={3}", listItem.SponsorID, listItem.FirstBAID, listItem.SecondBAID, listItem.ThirdBAID );
}
```

There may be syntactical errors but the approach remains same.

Feel free to leave a message!

Comment: You don't need that additional `SponsorInfoList`

Answer (score -2):

You need to deserialize into your object like:

```
Sponsor spon = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sponsor>(json);
```

Comment: You will not get a list of `SponsorInfo` objects. See other answers.